# How do get the Manufacturer string to show up in the msconfig Startup tab?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, configuration-files

I have a C# application that I have developed in Visual Studio 2010 that, upon installation is placed in the user's Startup folder so that the application launches in the tray each time the user logs on. I have set the Manufacturer string in the VS setup project and it shows up correctly in the Add/Remove Programs part of Control Panel. The problem is that when we launch msconfig.exe and look at the Startup tab, the Manufacturer column says "Unknown". I cannot find any posts on the web that tell me where msconfig.exe gets its Manufacturer string. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

MSConfig.exe knows beans about your installer, it only looks at the actual executable.  There isn't any way to match an .exe file to the installer that copied the file.

So it uses a different source of the info it displays, the .exe file itself.  It uses the Authenticode certificate that's embedded in the file.  Any commercial program has one.  But yes, it is likely to missing from yours because buying a certificate from the likes of Verisign costs a lot of money.  Notable is the certificate is also used to display the name of the publisher in the UAC prompt when the app asks for elevation.  It is the most reliable way to get the real name, anything else can be too easily spoofed.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the assembly information for your application using the [Assembly Information Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h52t681.aspx).

From MSDN:

> To access this dialog box, select a project node in Solution Explorer,
>   and then, on the Project menu, click Properties. When the Project
>   Designer appears, click the Application tab. On the Application page,
>   click the Assembly Information button.

The manufacturer column in the msconfig startup list relates to the Company field in the Assembly Information Dialog.

Hope this helps.